# search function is not outputing correct ? (PHP)

Tags: php, html, database

### Hey im messing with a search function currently and i want it to display how many affected lines it is on the table and then echo it. but my code is working but its outputing wrong.

EDIT : Now it just displays 0 and search reseult , i wanna make it search for what they want in the table acksearch and then display how many results there was and then output it and display all that matched.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("acksocial");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Acksearch WHERE name = name ");
$rc = mysql_affected_rows();
echo "There was  " . $rc .        "    results of your search!";


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

---

now it just displays 0 and search reseult , i wanna make it search for what they want in the table acksearch and then display how many results there was and then output it and display all that matched.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve querying for rows `WHERE name = name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

---

Not quite sure from the look of your query... but hope this helps

```
<?php
//Connect
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("acksocial");
//Query all from Acksearch where name matches $_GET['name']
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Acksearch 
                        WHERE name="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']).'"');
//Count the rows after result was returned
$totalResults=mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "There is {$totalResults} results of your search!";
//If data is found loop it
if($totalResults>=1){
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo $row['name'];
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
?>
--Or--
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("acksocial");
//Count rows in the database then return that value
$result = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT count(1) as totalRows
                                    FROM Acksearch 
                                    WHERE name="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']).'"'),0,'totalRows');

echo "There was {$result['totalRows']} results of your search!";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE name = name` will always evaluate to true. Did you mean `$name`? What is your wrong output?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the php manual, you'll see that [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) has nothing to do with `SELECT` statements:

> Get the number of affected rows by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query associated with link_identifier.

You want [`mysql_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) instead:

> Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. This command is only valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result set. To retrieve the number of rows affected by a INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query, use mysql_affected_rows().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Acksearch WHERE name = 'name'");
```